# How do i update time in pygame in real time

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to display how long the game has been running for in real time. To do this, i have used `self.time_passed = pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000` and called it as `g.write("Time: %d" %(g.time_passed), g.white ,10, 10, 50)`. My write function looks like this:

```
def write(self, text, color, x , y, size):
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("airel", size)
            text = font.render(text, True, color)
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            self.screen.blit(text,(x , y))
```

My probelm is that the time is not updated in real time. It only updates the number of seconds everytime the player dies, even though i placed `g.write("Time: %d" %(g.time_passed), g.white ,10, 10, 50)` inside my main `while True:` game loop. Thanks for help.

Comment: *"It only updates the number of seconds everytime the player dies"* - then you did something wrong. *"even though i placed [...] inside my main `while True`"* - you have to show the code, where you call `write`! The `write` function is completely irrelevant for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would use time.time()

```
import time

start = time.time()

# your code

end = time.time()
duration = end - start # answer in seconds
print(duration)
```

Also you might want to just declare the font once like this:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

font18 = pygame.font.SysFont("ariel", 18)

displaysurf = pygame.display.init((1280, 720))

def write(f, t, x, y, c):
    textsurf = f.render(t, True, c)
    displaysurf.blit(textsurf, (x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because the system font is called `Arial` and not `airel`. Or maybe you are using the font `Aerial`?

This probably causes this funcion to fail and the one called when the player dies works fine.